# Finding multiple attributes within the span tag in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are two values that i am looking to scrape from a website. These are present in the following tags:

```
<span class="sp starBig">4.1</span>
<span class="sp starGryB">2.9</span>
```

I need the values sp starBig, sp starGryB.

The findAll expression that i am using is -

```
soup.findAll('span', {'class': ['sp starGryB', 'sp starBig']}):
```

The code gets executed without any errors yet no results get displayed.

Comment: Which version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: there is a ':' at the end..

Comment: do you need the values **of** sp starBig and sp starGryB ?

Comment: @skyline75489 Sry.I am not sure which version it is. How do i find out? I am newbie.

Comment: Did you import bs4 or BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @skyline75489 yes i need the values of sp starBig and sp starGryB. I am able to get those values when i use either sp starBig or sp starGryB, but not when i use both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class), assuming Beautiful Soup 4, matching for multiple CSS classes with strings like `'sp starGryB'` is brittle and should not be done:

```
soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'sp starGryB'})
# [<span class="sp starGryB">2.9</span>]
soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'starGryB sp'})
# []
```

[CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) should be used instead, like so:

```
soup.select('span.sp.starGryB')
# [<span class="sp starGryB">2.9</span>]
soup.select('span.starGryB.sp')
# [<span class="sp starGryB">2.9</span>]
```

In your case:

```
items = soup.select('span.sp.starGryB') + soup.select('span.sp.starBig')
```

or something more sophisticated like:

```
items = [i for s in ['span.sp.starGryB', 'span.sp.starBig'] for i in soup.select(s)]
```

Comment: items = [i for s in ['span.sp.starGryB', 'span.sp.starBig']
    for i in soup.select(s):
        try:
            print(i.string)
        except KeyError:
            pass

Comment: items = soup.select('span.sp.starGryB') + soup.select('span.sp.starBig') is working.

Comment: @Dixon The second option is just using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), the expression inside and including `[]`, not a standard for loop. Removed the line split to hopefully improve clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is a better way, but it is eluding me at present. It can be done with css selectors like this:

```
html = '''<span class="sp starBig">4.1</span>
          <span class="sp starGryB">2.9</span>
          <span class="sp starBig">22</span>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

selectors = ['span.sp.starBig', 'span.sp.starGryB']
result = []
for s in selectors:
    result.extend(soup.select(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

soup.findAll('span', {'class': ['sp starGryB', 'sp starBig']})
this code is helpful and it's work very good with me

Comment: Hi, how is this different from the code in the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).