# Beautifulsoup how does findAll work

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've noticed some weird behavior of `findAll`'s method:

```
>>> htmls="<html><body><p class=\"pagination-container\">slytherin</p><p class=\"pagination-container and something\">gryffindor</p></body></html>"
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(htmls, "html.parser")
>>> for i in soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-container"}):
    print(i.text)


slytherin
gryffindor
>>> for i in soup.findAll("p", {"class":"pag"}):
    print(i.text)


>>> for i in soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-container"}):
    print(i.text)


slytherin
gryffindor
>>> for i in soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination"}):
    print(i.text)


>>> len(soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-container"}))
2
>>> len(soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-containe"}))
0
>>> len(soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-contai"}))
0
>>> len(soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-container and something"}))
1
>>> len(soup.findAll("p",{"class":"pagination-conta"}))
0
```

So, when we search for `pagination-container` it returns both the first and the second `p` tag. It made me think that it looks for a partial equality: something like `if passed_string in class_attribute_value:`. So I shortened the string in `findAll` method and it never managed to find anything!

How is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [`class`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) is a special [multi-valued space-delimited attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) and has a special handling.

When you write `soup.findAll("p", {"class":"pag"})`, `BeautifulSoup` would search for elements having class `pag`. It would split element class value by space and check if there is `pag` among the splitted items. If you had an element with `class="test pag"` or `class="pag"`, it would be matched.

Note that in case of `soup.findAll("p", {"class": "pagination-container and something"})`, `BeautifulSoup` would match an element having the exact `class` attribute value. There is no splitting involved in this case - it just sees that there is an element where the complete `class` value equals the desired string.

To have a *partial match on one of the classes*, you can provide a [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) or [a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) as a class filter value:

```
import re

soup.find_all("p", {"class": re.compile(r"pag")})  # contains pag
soup.find_all("p", {"class": re.compile(r"^pag")})  # starts with pag

soup.find_all("p", {"class": lambda class_: class_ and "pag" in class_})  # contains pag
soup.find_all("p", {"class": lambda class_: class_ and class_.startswith("pag")})  # starts with pag
```

---

There is much more to say, but you should also know that `BeautifulSoup` has [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) support (a limited one but covers most of the common use cases). You can write things like:

```
soup.select("p.pagination-container")  # one of the classes is "pagination-container"
soup.select("p[class='pagination-container']")  # match the COMPLETE class attribute value
soup.select("p[class^=pag]")  # COMPLETE class attribute value starts with pag
```

---

Handling `class` attribute values in `BeautifulSoup` is a common source of confusion and questions, please see these related topics to gain more understanding:

- [BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288969/beautifulsoup-returns-empty-list-when-searching-by-compound-class-names)
- [Finding multiple attributes within the span tag in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877663/finding-multiple-attributes-within-the-span-tag-in-python)