# How to extract onClick url using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Below is the `HTML` code which needs extraction

```html
<div class="one_block" style="display:block;" onClick="location.href=\'/games/box.html
?&game_type=01&game_id=13&game_date=2020-04-19&pbyear=2020\';" style="cursor:pointer;">
<!-- \xe5\xb0\x8d\xe6\x88\xb0\xe7\x90\x83\xe9\x9a\x8
a\xe5\x8f\x8a\xe5\xa0\xb4\xe5\x9c\xb0 start -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="schedule_team">
<tr>
```

How do I get the `location.href` value?

Tried:

```
soup.findAll("div", {"onClick": "location.href"})
```

Returns `null`

`Desired Output:`

```
/games/box.html?&game_type=01&game_id=13&game_date=2020-04-19&pbyear=2020
```

> PS: there's plenty of `location.href`

Comment: Hi, did you try regular expression ?
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup.find_all('a', {'onClick': re.compile(r'location.href')})

Comment: No, but why `regex`? I feel `regex` takes up more time

Comment: Its just an advice...maybe you can try it and use a profiler to track performance issues

Comment: I just tried, didn't work the code you provided

Comment: You can get some context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840221/beautifulsoup-how-does-findall-work

Comment: sorry there was a mistake here....try with escape : soup.find_all('a', {'onClick': re.compile(r'location\.href')})

Comment: @yAzou didn't work bro

Comment: what didn't work ? you still get None ? or you got an error ?

Comment: @yAzou None, empty

Comment: @johnrao07 what's the desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How about using [.select() method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for [SoupSieve package](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/) to run a CSS selector*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="one_block" style="display:block;" onClick="location.href=\'/games/box.html?&game_type=01&game_id=13&game_date=2020-04-19&pbyear=2020\';" style="cursor:pointer;">' \
        '<!-- \xe5\xb0\x8d\xe6\x88\xb0\xe7\x90\x83\xe9\x9a\x8a\xe5\x8f\x8a\xe5\xa0\xb4\xe5\x9c\xb0 start -->' \
        '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="schedule_team"><tr>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
element = soup.select('div.one_block')[0]
print(element.get('onclick'))
```

*Use split to get just* `print(element.get('onclick').split("'")[1])`

```
/games/box.html?&game_type=01&game_id=13&game_date=2020-04-19&pbyear=2020
```

Comment: The output is ` location.href='/games/box.html?&game_type=01&game_id=25&game_date=2020-04-29&pbyear=2020';`, needs further string manupulation to get the url, can it be done via code

Comment: What output you need?

Comment: Never mind I see it on ur op, I will try run test later

Comment: Maybe `print(element.get('onclick').split("'")[1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to learn from your posts. They are great resource.