# selecting itemTitle in h1- beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

if not response.ok:
    print('Server Responded: ', response.status_code)
else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):
    #price
    #item

    h1 = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle')
    print(h1)


def main():
    url = "https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Longines-Master-Collection-Automatic-40mm-White-Mens-Watch-L2-909-4-78-3/383525040495?hash=item594bdfb16f:g:vdIAAOSwytheqbKu"

    get_detail_data(get_page(url))



if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

[hi please help me with how I can select the item name on e-bay. The item name is the title of the watch. I managed to get to the  then to itemTitle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atFHA.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Example*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url=url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('Server Responded: ', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
        return soup


def get_detail_data(soup):
    h1 = soup.select("span.g-hdn")[0]
    print(h1.next_sibling)
    return h1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Longines-Master-Collection-Automatic-40mm-White-Mens-Watch-L2-909-4-78-3/383525040495?hash=item594bdfb16f:g:vdIAAOSwytheqbKu"
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))
```

---

Prints out

> ```
> New Longines Master Collection Automatic 40mm White Men's Watch L2.909.4.78.3
> ```

Comment: what if I want "New Longines Master Collection Automatic 40mm White Men's Watch L2.909.4.78.3"?

Comment: I am getting "Details about   New Longines Master Collection Automatic 40mm White Men's Watch L2.909.4.78.3." How do I extract "New Longines Master Collection Automatic 40mm White Men's Watch L2.909.4.78.3."

Comment: sorry I have been little busy - see updated answer-

Comment: what resources can you recommend inorder to sharpen my skills?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467369/4539709 - see this answer it has link @H-petes let me know

Comment: Please help me extract price @0m3r

Comment: Post new question please , I will try to help you