# Beautiful Soup. How to find tags with specific attribute but different attribute values in one search?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all posts from a forum topic with one search request in order to get a list with the posts in correct order. Most of the posts I can get with:

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'post_wrap'}
```

But there also are posts that can be found with:

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'post_wrap__staff'}
```

So, the attribute is the same, but the attribute value is different. Can I get both types of posts in one request? Something like:

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'post_wrap' and 'post_wrap__staff'}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding multiple attributes within the span tag in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877663/finding-multiple-attributes-within-the-span-tag-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This depends on what version of BeautifulSoup you are using. Looking at [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) for bs3 it looks like what you are looking for is something like the following</s>

```
soup.findAll(class=['post_wrap', 'post_wrap__staff']}
```

As you tagged it with *Python 3* I assume you are using bs4. [The docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) state that you can do something like the below:

```
soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": ["post_wrap", "post_wrap__staff"]})
```

But as noted in [a similar question about multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877663/finding-multiple-attributes-within-the-span-tag-in-python), it might be better to [use CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) like the below:

```
result = soup.find_all("div", class_=["post_wrap", "post_wrap__staff"])
```